# How to control different tags with the same variable in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to use the same variable with different tags

```
const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
const activeFolder = click ? "-active" : ""

<li
  className={"gnb__folder " + activeFolder}
    onClick={() => {
      setClick(check ^ true)
    }}
>
```

this code works. but, I don't know how to do the same, if I want to use the same variable to control different tags?

like this,

```
const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
const activeFolder = click ? "-active" : ""

<li
  className={"gnb__folder " + activeFolder}
    onClick={() => {
      setClick(check ^ true)
    }}
>
</li>
<li
  className={"gnb__folder " + activeFolder}
    onClick={() => {
      setClick(check ^ true)
    }}
>
</li>
```

There are two tags in code and I want to control each.
I want to control ***activeFolder*** variable

Comment: Are you facing any error?

Comment: no, but I want add "-active" or ""(nothing) each,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to solve your problem :

```
const [folders, setFolders] = useState([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]);
const [folderSelected, setFolderSelected] = useState();

const clicked = id => () => {
  folderSelected === id ? setFolderSelected() : setFolderSelected(id);
};

return folders.map(folder => {
  const activeFolder = folder.id === folderSelected ? "-active" : "";
  return (
    <li
      className={"gnb__folder " + activeFolder}
      onClick={this.clicked(folder.id)}
    >
      test
    </li>
  );
});
```